# mrtg configuration

Tags: debian, configuration, monitoring, raspberry-pi

I installed mrtg and want add CPU, Memory graphs of local machine (not router) . Traffic graphs page working properly.Tried to find tutorial how to do that but:

I do not have `mrtg` dir on `/etc` to store cpu and memory `*.cfg`

My MIBs loacated not in `/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt` but in `/usr/shares/mibs/netsnmp/` and not as txt files.

Version: Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7-v7+

Any suggestions?